# Parsing an Amazon Review File With Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I would like to create a table out of an amazon review file that has the following format

```
product/productId: B00006HAXW
review/userId: A1RSDE90N6RSZF
review/profileName: Joseph M. Kotow
review/helpfulness: 9/9
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1042502400
review/summary: Pittsburgh - Home of the OLDIES
review/text: I have all of the doo wop DVD's and this one is as good or better than the
1st ones. Remember once these performers are gone, we'll never get to see them again.
Rhino did an excellent job and if you like or love doo wop and Rock n Roll you'll LOVE
this DVD !!
```

My SQL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE reviews (id int, user_id int, profile_name int, helpfulness string, review_score float, review_time int, review_summary string, review_text string)
```

I´m aware that hive can load data using line and fields delimitators. But here I don´t have the same format on every line. Can anyone help me use hive to parse this file format so I can load it into my file system.?

Thank you !

Comment: Is it exact format?. I saw somewhere that Amazon Review data comes in json format.

Comment: It may, the problem is that I need to parse this specific file which is just a .txt . You can check it here: https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Movies.html